# How to serialize POJO to xml with namespace prefix

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, xstream, jaxb2

Spring offers several ways to convert POJO to XML through HttpMessageConverter.  However, I am having quite a bit of difficulty finding one that supports custom namespace with prefix.

For example from

```
public class Student {
   String name;
   String address;
   Integer score;
}
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<foo:Student xmlns:foo="http://schemas.foo.com/student">
   <foo:name>Some Name</foo:name>
   <foo:address>Address</foo:address>
   <foo:score>95</foo:score>
</foo:Student>
```

I was happily using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with jackson-dataformat-xml until I realized that it does not support custom prefix.

Then I looked into using MarshallingHttpMessageConverter with XStreamMarshaller, only to find out that XStream does not support custom prefix either.

Can anyone refer me to a example how I can serialize POJO to xml with custom namespace prefix? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to resolve similar problem for Jackson. First you have to use woodstox XML processor.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Than I have added namespace perfix/uri mapping this way:

```
  XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
  // override default instance of WstxOutputFactory
  mapper.getFactory().setXMLOutputFactory(new WstxOutputFactory() {
    @Override
    public XMLStreamWriter createXMLStreamWriter(Writer w) throws XMLStreamException {
      mConfig.setProperty(WstxInputProperties.P_RETURN_NULL_FOR_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,  true);
      XMLStreamWriter result = super.createXMLStreamWriter(w);
      result.setPrefix("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
      return result;
    }
  });
```

For sure this is not elegant soultion but I am not sure if there is any other way. I hope Jackson will add api support for prefixes in future release.

I guess however in your case default namespace with prefix is needed and this seems to be more difficult because Jackson does not support default namespace (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/18) and even using class inheritance with `@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace="http://xmlns.uri.com")` you still would need to annotate each property with `@JacksonXmlProperty(namespace="http://xmlns.uri.com")`

Comment: What if I want the prefix only on the root element ?

Comment: That didn't work for me, with no namespaces being output. The line setting an input property seems suspicious to me, but replacing it with
`mConfig.enableAutomaticNamespaces(true);`
worked wonders.